# A regex to match specific coordinates in a string

Tags: regex

-Z and S are coordinates that belong together

-There is always a 'Z' and an 'S'. There are no restrictions on the string that falls between 'Z' and 'S'

-The first letter is always Z

-If the letter S is followed by a : the search should stop, it's a match; coordinates complete

-If the next character after the S is (, then it should search till only next )

-so if there is a : or a ) after the S, its a match

-if the next character after the S is a +-*/ the search schould stop, its also a match

So far i have this regex `Z.*?S(?:(?=:)|.*?\))`

My string could be like this:

```
string cell = "SUM(Z(-44)S:Z(-1)S)"
```

Matches => Z(-44)S and Z(-1)S

```
string cell = "=ZS(-2)+ZS(-1)+0,00"
```

Matches => ZS(-2) and ZS(-1)

```
string cell = "SUM(Z(-1)S(-4):Z(12)S(-2))"
```

Matches => Z(-1)S(-4) and Z(12)S(-2)

```
 string cell = "Z(-44)S:Z(36)S(4)"
```

Matches => Z(-44)S and Z(36)S(4)

```
string cell = "Z(-44)S:Z(36)S"
```

Matches => Z(-44)S and Z(36)S

```
string cell = "(+Z55S+Z63S56+Z110S+Z142S+Z172S56+0)"
```

Matches => Z55S and Z63S56 and Z110S and Z142S and Z172S56

```
string cell = "(+Z63S56+Z110S(4)+0)"
```

Matches => Z63S56 and Z110S(4)

I hope this is understandable
I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Sounds like you want `Z.*?S(?:\([^()]*\)|[^-+*/:]+(?=[-+*/:]))?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fc8oi3/1))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works! Thx you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

```
Z.*?S(?:\([^)]+\))?(?:\d+)?
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq59S7/2)

---

- `Z.*?S` - Literal Z, any character zero or more times non-greedy till literal S.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group.

  - `\([^)]+\))` - A literal opening paranthesis following by anything other than closing paranthesis one or more and a literal closing paranthesis.
- `)?` - Close 1st non-capture group and make it optional.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group.

  - `\d+` - Any digit one or more time.
- `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.